# Storing decimals in sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using the Roo gem to import some values from a spreadsheet.

One cell has the value 9.29

But after import it gets saved as 9.289999999999999

So i added to import method:

```
product.standard_price = row["standard_price"].to_f.round(2)
```

which i believe should round it, but no changes.

I also changed the column precision like this

change_column :products, :standard_price, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2

but still it gets stored as 9.289999999999999

Even when I edit this entry and put in 9.29 it get stored with all those decimals.

This is a mystery to me

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is best to store prices as an integer. So you would have to multiply by 100 and store the value e.g. 929. Then when you come to displaying the number, just divide the number you get from the database by 100.

Alternatively you can store it in text format.

Comment: Hmm sounds a bit strange. If the decimal type cant even keep good track of 2 decimals what good is it then?

Comment: SQLite has no decimal type.

Comment: Is there a way to display n/100 in decimal format in a named form element, but have the underlying integer n be the element's value at HTTP request time?